# wp_list_widget_controls() undefined

Tags: widgets

I'm using Wordpress 4.8 with PHP 7.1, and although there's a function called [wp_list_widget_controls()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_widget_controls/) in the documentation, everytime I try to call it I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: 
Call to undefined function wp_list_widget_controls() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-content/plugins/Global Sidebar Server/menu_page.php:64 

Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-admin/includes/template.php(1365): global_sidebar_server_sidebar_list_html(Array) 
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-admin/includes/template.php(1324): do_settings_fields('global_sidebar_...', 'global_sidebar_...') 
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-content/plugins/Global Sidebar Server/menu_page.php(13): do_settings_sections('global_sidebar_...') 
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): global_sidebar_server_options_page_html('') 
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) 
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) 
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-admin/admin.php(222): do_action('settings_page_g...') 
#7 /opt/lampp in /opt/lampp/htdocs/global_menu_server/wp-content/plugins/Global Sidebar Server/menu_page.php on line 64
```

The installation is a fresh installation with default theme (Twenty Seventeen).

Comment: it look like something wrong with your plugin Global Sidebar Server.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to call `wp_list_widget_controls` in this plugin.